# How to create date from year, month and day in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have three columns about year, month and day. How can I use these to create date in PySpark?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `concat_ws()` to concat columns with `-` and cast to date.

```
#sampledata
df.show()

#+----+-----+---+
#|year|month|day|
#+----+-----+---+
#|2020|   12| 12|
#+----+-----+---+
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("date",concat_ws("-",col("year"),col("month"),col("day")).cast("date")).show()
+----+-----+---+----------+
|year|month|day|      date|
+----+-----+---+----------+
|2020|   12| 12|2020-12-12|
+----+-----+---+----------+

#dynamic way
cols=["year","month","day"]
df.withColumn("date",concat_ws("-",*cols).cast("date")).show()
#+----+-----+---+----------+
#|year|month|day|      date|
#+----+-----+---+----------+
#|2020|   12| 12|2020-12-12|
#+----+-----+---+----------+

#using date_format,to_timestamp,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp) functions

df.withColumn("date",date_format(concat_ws("-",*cols),"yyyy-MM-dd").cast("date")).show()
df.withColumn("date",to_timestamp(concat_ws("-",*cols),"yyyy-MM-dd").cast("date")).show()
df.withColumn("date",to_date(concat_ws("-",*cols),"yyyy-MM-dd")).show()
df.withColumn("date",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat_ws("-",*cols),"yyyy-MM-dd"),"yyyy-MM-dd").cast("date")).show()
#+----+-----+---+----------+
#|year|month|day|      date|
#+----+-----+---+----------+
#|2020|   12| 12|2020-12-12|
#+----+-----+---+----------+
```

Comment: The example(2020-12-12) taken is very simple. But how does it work with year=2020, month=1, day=1?

Comment: Hi @Munesh, I suppose you were worrying about single-digit months and/or days, I thought the same. I tested it, the following is an example from a test dataframe, last column is the result: `|2021|    5| 24| 2021-05-24|`.

Comment: Your last approach might give you the right value but the first 2 approaches would result in `2021-5-24`

Answer (score 9):

For Spark 3+, you can use [`make_date`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#make_date) function:

```
df = df.withColumn("date", expr("make_date(year, month, day)"))
```

Comment: From Spark 3.3, it's already in Python API: `F.make_date('year', 'month', 'day')`

Answer (score 0):

Using pyspark on DataBrick, here is a solution when you have a pure string; unix_timestamp may not work unfortunately and yields wrong results. be very causious when using unix_timestamp, or to_date commands in pyspark.
for example if your string has a fromat like "20140625" they simply generate totally wrong version of input dates. In my case no method works except concatantion from building the string again and cast it as date as follows.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, substring, concat

# string format to deal with: "20050627","19900401",...

#Create a new column with a shorter name to keep the originalcolumns as well
df.withColumn("dod",col("date_of_death"))

#create date upon string components
df.withColumn("dod", concat(substring(df.dod,1,4),lit("-"),substring(df.dod,5,2),lit("-"),substring(df.dod,7,2)).cast("date")))
```

the results look like this:

[image]

beware of using the following format. it most probabily and oddly generates wrong results without raising and showing you any error. in my case it ruinedd most of my analsyse:

```
### wrong use! use only on strings with delimeters ("yyyy-mm-dd) and be highly causious!
f.to_date(f.unix_timestamp(df.dod,"yyyymmdd").cast("timestamp"))
```